# Simple boolean inequality operators mistake

Tags: python, return, boolean, inequality

Using inequality operators, I have to define a procedure `weekend` which takes a string as its input and returns the boolean `True` if it's 'Saturday' or 'Sunday' and `False` otherwise.

Here is my code

```
def weekend(day):
    if day != 'Saturday' or day != 'Sunday':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This seemingly returns `False` to every day, I don't know why, logically it would work... Can anyone please explain?

Comment: By DeMorgan's: `x != a or y != b` is the same as `!(x == a and y == b)`. It should be clear that, since `x == y` and `a != b` this creates a corundum: `!(x == a and x == b)` -> `!(true and false)` *or* `!(false and true)` -> `!(false)` -> `true` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Fixed version:***

```
if day != 'Saturday' and day != 'Sunday'
```

***Better version:***

```
return day in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

***Why `or` doesn't work:***

When you use `or`, your condition would read something like "if today is not Saturday or today is not Sunday". Now replace "today" by "Saturday":

> If Saturday is not Saturday or Saturday is not Sunday

The statement "Saturday is not Saturday" is obviously false and "Saturday is not Sunday" is obviously true, so the entire statement becomes "if false or true", which is always true.

Replace "today" by any other day and you will find that the sentence always evaluates to one of these sentences, which are always true:

```
if True or False  # day = Sunday
if False or True  # day = Saturday
if True or True   # any other day
```

Comment: Indeed, the latter version if by far the clearest and most pythonic way to do it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you tell me why 'or' doesn't work?

Comment: @user1561559 I added an explanation of why 'or' does not work here.

Comment: +1 for including explanation of problem and the "better version" way of doing it. (Beat me to the punch while I was writing out my long-winded answer haha.)

Answer (score 5):

The best way to deal with this, use something like this:

```
return day.lower() in ['saturday','sunday']
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean `and`

```
def weekend(day):
    if day != 'Saturday' and day != 'Sunday':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

or the clearer version (which just applies De Morgan to the above):

```
def weekend(day):
    if day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The day will always be different from **one** of both days.

Comment: Reverse that! `if day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday': return True`

Comment: Indeed, by bad, I explained it right, but wrote the example wrong.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Tip for the future:** think through your code as if you were the computer *in excruciating detail*. For example, I would literally have this conversation with myself:

Hmm, when `day = 'Saturday'`, the code is returning `False` even though I think it shouldn't. Let's see what's going on line-by-line.

`def weekend(day):`

- Okay that seems good from now on I'll replace `day` with `'Saturday'` anytime I see it...

`if day != 'Saturday' or day != 'Sunday':`

- Okay so I'll mentally translate this to `if 'Saturday' != 'Saturday' or 'Saturday' != 'Sunday':` .
- Now I'll simplify it by evaluating the comparisons.

  - `'Saturday' != 'Saturday'` becomes `False`
  - `'Saturday' != 'Sunday':` becomes `True`
- Plugging those in, I see that the `if` statement is saying `if False or True`, which is the same as `if True`. So that means that `day = Saturday` leads to a return value of `False` .

Aha, so now I see what was wrong with the `day = 'Saturday'` case; the `day != 'Sunday'` condition meant that the `if` evaluated to `True`.

So while the code below would return `True` for `day = 'Saturday'`,

```
def weekend(day):
    if day != 'Saturday':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

and this code would work for `day = 'Sunday'`,

```
def weekend(day):
    if day != 'Sunday':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

the two cannot be combined with an `or`.

So try to talk to yourself like that in the future- it's super useful for debugging, especially when there is confusing boolean logic.

(For the record, I think that `return day.lower() in ['saturday','sunday']` is the best way to approach this.)

Answer (score 0):

```python
def weekend(day):
    # your code here
    if day == 'Saturday' or day == 'Sunday':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this answer for [Can not get “while” statement to progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587268/can-not-get-while-statement-to-progress), but it was marked as a duplicate right before I submitted it. And it is an exact logical duplicate (`x != foo or y != bar`), so I'm posting this here in hopes that my answer might help somebody.

The answer is reproduced verbatim.

---

Your problem is here:

```
while username != logindata.user1 or username != logindata.user2:
...
while password != logindata.passw1 or password != logindata.passw2:
```

The username loop in English is something like, "Keep looping if the provided `username` is either not equal to `user1`, or not equal to `user2`." Unless `user1` and `user2` are the same, no string will ever let that evaluate to `False`. If 'username' is equal to `user1`, it cannot be equal to `user2` (again, assuming `user1 != user2`, which is the case here).

The quick fix is to change the `or` to `and`. That way, you're checking whether `username` is not either of the available options. A better way to write that would be:

```
while not (username == logindata.user1 or username == logindata.user2):
```

But I would say that the correct way to write it, given what you're trying to do, is this:

```
while username not in [logindata.user1, logindata.user2]:
```

In English, something like, "Keep looping while the username is not in this list of usernames."

P.S. I was going to use a set instead of a list, for pedantic correctness, but it really doesn't matter for this, so I figured a list would be easier for a beginner. Just mentioning it before someone else does :).