# Can not get "while" statement to progress

Tags: python, while-loop, python-import

I had previously made a simple logging in code and it was working but when i went to separate data from the code to another .py file and import it, it will not progress passed the "username: " input part (it keeps loading the input for username). Does that mean that the file is not being imported correctly or is it in the main code?

**Login.py**

```
print ("Loading please wait...")

import logindata 
import inputdata
import time

time.sleep(1.5)

username = ""
while username != logindata.user1 or username != logindata.user2:
    print ("Username: ")
    username = input()

password = ""
while password != logindata.passw1 or password != logindata.passw2:
    print ("password")
    password = input()

if username == logindata.user1 and password == logindata.passw1:
    print ("Logging in...")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("Welcome, user1!")


if username == logindata.user2 and password == logindata.passw2:
    print ("Logging in...")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("Welcome, user2!")
```

**logindata.py**

```
#Login Data#
user1 = "user1"
passw1 = "pass1"
user2 = "user2"
passw2 = "pass2"
############
```

It was previously working before i added a second "user" to it.

Comment: I was about to post an answer when this was marked as a duplicate. Since the answer was relevant to the preexisting question, I posted it there. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912037/python-simple-boolean-inequality-operators-mistake/53587409#53587409).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
while username != logindata.user1 or username != logindata.user2:
```

If `user1` and `user2` are different, than the condition will always evaluate to false. You'll want to use `and` rather than `or`.

Also, you'll probably want to connect the username & password, and not allow user1 to login with the password for user2 and vice versa ...

Answer (score 0):

Change the `or` to an `and`.

```
username = ""
while username != logindata.user1 and username != logindata.user2:
    print ("Username: ")
    username = input()

password = ""
while password != logindata.passw1 and password != logindata.passw2:
    print ("password")
    password = input()
```

When you type in something that matches `logindata.user1`, `user != logindata.user2` evaluates to `True` and the loop continues. Therefore, you need the username to not match **both** `logindata.user1` *and* `logindata.user2`. Same goes for the password.